# Determine upper and lower bound of list of values

Tags: excel, vba

Column A contains a list of identical values which are unique among the column. The length of this list is not known. What is the most effienct way to determine the upper and lower bound of the list?

```
A   | B  | C | ...
--------------------------
... |
AAA | 
AAA |
AAA | 
AAA |
AAA |
AAA |
... |
```

Of course this can be solved by iterating down and up the list from the start postion until you hit a different value. But with larger lists I doubt this is a good solution. Is there any built-in excel function usable in this scenario which would give me a performance advantage?

Comment: How should the user clicking on the list effect its length? That seems simply irrelevant. Could you explain more clearly what the problem is?

Comment: True @John Coleman, I removed this. It's just the event triggering the function. I can solve the problem. This is a performance question as to whether this can be solved with a built-in excel function.

Comment: Is each "list of identical values" unique along the column? Or can there be two (or more) "AAA" lists?

Comment: It is unique @ user3598756

Comment: Binary search is a natural way to go.

Comment: So you'd use Worksheet_SelectionChange() event handler, wouldn't you?

Comment: @snflurry For Excel functions, you can use `MATCH` to find the first item, and `LOOKUP` to find the last.  In VBA, if there is only a single range containing the unique items, you can use the `Range.Find` method with a search direction depending on whether looking for first or last)

Comment: Or MATCH and COUNTIF: for the first row: `=MATCH("AAA",A:A,0)` for the last: `MATCH("AAA",A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,"AAA")-1`  This works if they are always sorted and the like entries are together.

Comment: And if you're looking for a method in Excel GUI, `Ctrl+F`, set `what = AAA` and click `Find Next` while pressing `Shift`, will take the search backward (i.e to the last occurrence if you're on the first occurrence or before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than built in Excel functions as pointed by Scott Craner in comments, you could consider this little VBA function

```
Function GetArea(rng As Range) As String
    With rng.EntireColumn
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=rng.Value 'ActiveCell.Value
        GetArea= .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).address
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

to be exploited in your "Main" code as follows:

```
Sub Main()
    MsgBox getarea(Range("A12")) '<--| get the bound of the list one element of which is cell A12
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code you can adapt:

```
Sub TheOuterLimits()
    Dim r As Long, v As Variant
    Dim a1 As String, a2 As String
    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    v = ActiveCell.Value
    a1 = ""
    a2 = ""
    For i = r To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, c).Value <> v Then
            a1 = Cells(i, c).Address(0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    For i = r To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, c).Value <> v Then
            a2 = Cells(i, c).Address(0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox a1 & vbCrLf & a2
End Sub
```

[image]

The code tells you where the pattern began and where it ends.